# has_one update problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one

I have two models, User and Account. Each user may have one account.

Creating an account for a user works fine. My problem is that when I try to update the account, the previous accounts user_id is nullified and a new account row is created with the user_id. I do not want this happening. I want to update the existing row with the changes to account. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the code you're using for the `update` action?

Comment: @account = @user.account.build(params[:account]);


if @account.save
  ...
else
  ...
end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code

```
@account = @user.account.build(params[:account])
if @account.save 
   #... 
else 
   #...
end
```

you're building a new `account`. What you need is to update

```
if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
   #...
else
   #...
end
```

Comment: update_attributes is more elegant than update in this situation...good call

Comment: apparently i lost my "accepted solution" for this opinion :( bye bye points

Comment: Since Rails 2.3.8 you can add :update_only to force it to update the existing association instead of nullifying the old one:   accepts_nested_attributes_for :account, :update_only => true

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any code lets say this is how you create a user

```
user = User.create(:name => "bob")
```

Then you can associate the user with an account by specifying the **user_id**

```
account = Account.create(:user_id =>user.id, :status => "not activated")
```

Now lets say we want to to change the status of the account. We can call the updated method in rails http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002270 like this:

```
Account.update( account.id, :status => "activated")
```

I can be more helpful with more info.